# How to check if stripe subscription went to past_due from trialing or active?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a scenario where I need to take an action in our system for a past_due status on stripe. But it depends on whether the subscription went from active (which was paid at least once) or trialing (which was in trial period and the first payment fails). Is there any way I can distinguish between those 2 scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `customer.subscription.updated` webhook event you can listen to, this event contains the Subscription where you can check if the status is `past_due` [0].

For a Subscription that is `past_due`, there are 2 pieces of information to obtain to determine whether the Subscription has previously been paid for:

1. The Subscription’s `trial_end` [1]:
   This is one of the fields from the Subscription.
2. The latest invoice line item’s starting period [2]:
   `latest_invoice` is one of the fields from the Subscription, this is an Invoice id, upon retrieving the  relevant Invoice [3], the epoch timestamp of interest can be found via `lines.data[0].period.start`.

If the value of these two epoch timestamps match, this indicates the Subscription has never been paid for, i.e. the latest invoice was created when the trial ended and payment has not been successful.

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-status
[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-trial_end
[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/line_item#invoice_line_item_object-period-start
[3] https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/retrieve

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be the correct way to do it. However, there's no way I can trigger this webhook only on a status updates, right ? It'll trigger on every ``customer.subscription.updated`` and I need to handle it on the API, right ?

Comment: Thank you, you are correct `customer.subscription.updated` listens to all changes on the subscription, the check on the status needs to be handled on the API.